# Passing null to web method in C#

Tags: c#

I have given a web service Url. One of its methods have an argument that if I pass null it does something and if pass int does something else. I have added a service reference to project. C# does not accept passing null to that argument because it has implemented its interface to accept int and not int? (nullable int).

Please advise.

Comment: Is your situation similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7930593/33499)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do an horrible walkarround, parsing int.MinValue or int.MaxValue. I really don't like that solution and it's not a best practice, but could do the trick.

for exeample

```
public void DoSomething( int numofSomething )
{
    if ( numofSomething == int.MinValue )
    {
        // act as if numofSomething is null
    }
    else
    {
        // act as normal
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you are doing your code more horrible, because you are using a minvalue or maxvalue to represent a null. Do this only if changing the interface is not an option.

Comment: Hi. I am not coder of web service.It is somewhere on the web and I should just call it. I tried to change the definition of the method in the generated interface and change int parameter to int? but it raised an implementation error.

Comment: If the webservice expects an int, you will not be able to pass a null. In case you found some walkarround, you will provoke the error on the webservice host. If it's not prepared to work with nulls, I am affraid you cannot walkarround it. :(

Comment: They have themselves proposed that I should pass either null or a timestamp as int. In PHP I can easily pass null using nusoap however I am stuck in C# implementation.

Comment: timestamp as int? maybe they consider the parameter as null if it's bigger that some number. Maybe you can ask and simply pass something like a really big number and hope the webservice will take it as a null. Anyway, looks really weird and a bad practice.

Comment: It is a sms web service. I should pass null for sending right now or pass a timestamp for scheduling.

Comment: Pass the timestamp representing now?

Comment: So please give me code fpr converting DateTime.Now to Unix timestamp in UTC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa